# Draw horizontal and vertical tangents

Tags: python, matplotlib

The standard code for plotting lines from a point would be something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_tangents(x, y, tangents):
    plt.plot(x, y, 'b.')
    # set xlim/ylim
    plt.xlim([min(x)-50, max(x)+50])
    plt.ylim([min(y)-50, max(y)+50])

    for i, m in enumerate(tangents):
        tx = np.linspace(x[i] - 5, x[i] + 5)
        plt.plot(tx, m*(tx - x[i]) + y[i], 'r--', label=f"y={m}(x - {x[i]} + {y[i]}")
        
    plt.show()

# Working example
dummyx = np.linspace(50, 100)
dummyy = np.linspace(50, 100)
dummym = np.linspace(1, 1)
plot_tangents(dummyx, dummyy, dummym)

# Failing example
dummyx = np.linspace(50, 50)
dummyy = np.linspace(200, 550)
dummym = np.array([np.inf] * 50)
plot_tangents(dummyx, dummyy, dummym)
```

However when given vertical lines with linspace in x or horizontal lines with linspace in y, this code will fail to plot.

Is there anyway to get matplot to handle these cases - ideally I'd like to plot a limited segment length for the tangent rather than an x/y range.

[Expected tangents forming the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZV7B.png)

[Missing vertical line, no plot visible (which makes sense from the equation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf4Mj.png)

**Partial Solution**

The missing vertical line can be fixed with the following change to the line plot code - thanks @tdy - but understandably this is now an infinite line tangent.

```
plt.axline(xy1=(x[i], y[i]), slope=m, label=f'$y {-y[i]:+} = {m}(x {-x[i]:+})$')
```

Comment: The intention is to plot the tangents along the given points; normally these tangents are calculated separately but wanted to given a simple example without the tangent calculation.

Comment: Good point about the `linspace` - just was meant to be a quick way to mirror the expected gradients without calculating them (which is done in a separate process that is working correctly).

Comment: it looks like you're trying to plot a `y = m*x + b` line, so it's easiest to use `axline`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090008/13138364

Comment: @tdy Great! That works now:
`plt.axline(xy1=(x[i], y[i]), slope=m, label=f'$y {-y[i]:+} = {m}(x {-x[i]:+})$')`
Is there anyway to limit the line length without reference to x / y - e.g. using euclidean length. Otherwise vertical lines are unbounded in xmin / xmax.

Comment: `axline` is just for infinite lines, so if you want a bounded version, i guess you would still need `plot`. i'm a bit confused by the examples though. normally you'd want to plot tangents against some curve, right? so for every point of a given curve, are you trying to plot a tangent line measuring 5 units to either side of that point?

Comment: Pretty much - it's basically designed to visually demonstrate that the tangent code works.

The omitted step is that the tangent plots are bounded to a small region of the curve (to make it less cluttered).